# How to write Dictionary extension that handles optional values

Tags: swift, swift-dictionary

I'm trying to implement a `Dictionary` extension and I want to handle optional values. But whatever I do, if I use my method on a `[String: String?]` dictionary, it fails to optionally bind the value. How do you write an extension to a dictionary that gracefully handles optional values?

---

Consider the following extension:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func someMethod() {
        for (key, value) in self {
            if let valueString = value as? String {
                println("  \(key) = \(valueString)")
            } else {
                println("  \(key) = \(value) cannot be cast to `String`")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So consider the following code:

```
let dictionary: [String: AnyObject?] = ["foo": "bar"]
dictionary.someMethod()
```

And it curiously reports

```
foo = Optional(bar) cannot be cast to `String`
```

I can write a non-extension method that handles dictionary parameters with optional values, but don't see how to do it as an extension of `Dictionary`.

Comment: I can explain why it doesn't work as you seem to expect. When applied to an Optional, `as`, `is`, `as?`, and `==` (and the other comparators) have a special meaning: they are applied to the thing-wrapped. The reason why `if let valueString = value as? String` doesn't do what you seem to expect is that at compile time we don't know that `value` _is_ an Optional, and so we do not use the special meaning of `as` applied to an Optional. We try to cast the Optional _itself_ to a String, and of course that fails; you can't cast an Optional _itself_ to anything.

Comment: As you yourself have said, I believe, Swift seems to invite use of instance methods, but the actual power is in top-level global functions, because they allow you to construct a generic constraint that lets only the correct type through the mesh, as it were. Dictionary is a generic, and you can't add further constraints to a generic, so you'll never be able to do this with an instance method in an extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with reflection. Doesn't require much more code than you already have:

```
extension Dictionary
{
    func someMethod()
    {
        for (key, value) in self
        {
            var valueRef = _reflect(value)

            while valueRef.disposition == .Optional && valueRef.count > 0 && valueRef[0].0 == "Some"
            {
                valueRef = valueRef[0].1
            }

            if let valueString: String = valueRef.value as? String
            {
                print("  \(key) = \(valueString)")
            }
            else
            {
                print("  \(key) = \(value) cannot be cast to `String`")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let dictionary: [String : AnyObject?] = ["foo" : "bar"]
dictionary.someMethod()
```

Returns

```
foo = bar
```

---

```
let dictionary: [String : AnyObject?] = ["foo" : nil]
dictionary.someMethod()
```

Returns

```
foo = nil cannot be cast to `String`
```

---

```
let dictionary: [String : AnyObject?] = ["foo" : UIViewController()]
dictionary.someMethod()
```

Returns

```
foo = Optional(<UIViewController: 0x7fee7e819870>) cannot be cast to `String`
```

Answer (score 0):

I get no problems when I insert ':String?' right after valueString as shown below:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func someMethod() -> Bool {
        for (key, value) in self {
            if let valueString:String? = value as? String {
                println("  \(key) = \(valueString)")
            } else {
                println("  \(key) = \(value) cannot be cast to `String`")
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}

func doSomething() {
    let dictionary: [String: AnyObject?] = ["foo": "bar"]
    if dictionary.someMethod() {
        println("no problems")
    } else {
        println("casting issues")
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. When I do that, it doesn't fail and fall to the "cannot cast" (i.e. it returns `true`, but `valueString` is always `nil`, even if there was a value supplied.